# How we can rename labels in angular formio.io form builder when UI load

Tags: angular, typescript, rename, formbuilder, formio

[Rename select checkbox to multiselect how we can achieve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWH1q.png).

i have try to update node of formio from where label are coming but not able to find solution.
please help me to find solution make custom form builder that i can implement it in form builder to load my manually create customize form builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the JSON Schema definition, then you might be able to change the label.

Visit this [documentation](https://help.form.io/userguide/form-building/form-components#select-box), then click on the `json` tab. You will notice the first line is

`"label": "Select Boxes",`

Try changing that to below when you update your JSON Schema:

`"label": "MultiSelect Boxes",`